# RegGetValueA format/layout

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I am attempting to write a function that checks the registry value to see if color is enabled for the console on windows.

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\VirtualTerminalLevel
```

If you navigate to here through the registry, this is the value i need to retrieve. It is either 1 or 0, 1 being enabled 0 being disabled.

```
#include <Windows.h>
    DWORD val;
    DWORD dataSize = sizeof(val);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegGetValueA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Computer\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Console", "VirtualTerminalLevel", RRF_RT_DWORD, nullptr, &val, &dataSize)) {
        printf("Value is %i\n", val);
    }
    else {
        printf("Error reading.\n");
    }
```

This is my attempt. This always results in "error reading". My question is, What do i need to place in "subkey" and "value" args of the RegGetValueA function?

Comment: Your non-code example uses `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, but your code uses `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying the wrong path to the value.  Do not include `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER` in the `lpSubKey` parameter. That is only for human readability, not actually part of the path for the Registry API to use. The `lpSubKey` value is relative to the `hKey` root, which in this case should be `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, not `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD val;
DWORD dataSize = sizeof(val);

if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegGetValueA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Console", "VirtualTerminalLevel", RRF_RT_DWORD, nullptr, &val, &dataSize)) {
    printf("Value is %u”, val);
}
else {
    printf("Error reading.\n");
}
```

Comment: oh okay i see what i did, thank you for that. Just tested and it works.

Comment: Also, for next time, instead of printing just 'Error reading', print out also the error code.  It's there for a reason.